# Create a hierarchical loop at predefined markup requirements

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, fullpage.js

I try to achive this in wordpress based on my theme:
[fullpage.js demo](http://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/VvZXMP)

So I have a predefined markup for vertical sections (parents) and one for horizontal slides (children). Parents only contain posts if they have no children, if they have children, each post must be inside the child elements. There is one post per page.

Here is the required markup:

```
<div id="fullpage">

    <section class="vertical-scrolling"  data-anchor="//post title here//"> 
      <div //we can have another div here if you like //>
        <article id="//post id here//">
         // Here comes the content of a vertical section//
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="vertical-scrolling"  data-anchor="//taxonomy term here//">
        <div class="horizontal-scrolling" data-anchor="//post title here//">
            <article id="//post id here//">
             // Here comes the post-content with the taxonomy term for the first slide //
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal-scrolling" data-anchor="//post title here//">
            <article id="//post id here//">
             // Here comes the post-content with the taxonomy term for the second slide //
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Please help me to create a loop,

- that outputs specified posts as vertical sections,
- that outputs specified posts grouped for example by taxonomy term as horizontal slides
- that meets the given markup requirements.

Comment: `fp_main` is parent of `fp_slide`? Do you want to iterate over `fp_main` and for each one iterate over it's `fp_slide` children?

Comment: Correct, at the moment they both just exist next to each other. Do you think a hierarchical relation would help? Maybe there´s a better way than using post_types, I´m not limited to this. The only predefined thing is the different markup for both..

Comment: Yes, I think it would help, but if post types aren't really required I would suggest using a loopable group of fields with a plugin like ACF or Custom  Field Suite. If you think that would fit your needs I can post an answer detailing how to do it.

Comment: I really would appreciate this. Currently I use CPT UI. I found these related posts  ( https://goo.gl/ctFgF2, http://goo.gl/iQsrb5) but I wasn´t able to reach what I need.